# How to fix the buttons stop functioning after pressing multiple times?

Tags: android

The buttons on my app stops playing the music after pressing them repeatedly for multiple times and also after scanning a bunch of QR codes.

I have developed an app. It scans a QR code. QR code contains a number. The app draws the image related to that number and displays. Then a music also played in the background related to that number.
There are three buttons, Go Back, Song, Talk.
When Song button is pressed, the background music is played again.
When Talk button is pressed, a separate soundtrack is played and can be played again and again by pressing the button repeatedly. 
The Go Back button takes the user to the scanner screen.

Here is the Main Activity:

```
package com.example.folio;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;


import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.zxing.Result;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;
//import sun.applet.Main;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {


    private DatabaseReference databaseRef;


    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA=1;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private  Integer images[]={
            R.drawable.pussinboots,
            R.drawable.mickeymouse,
            R.drawable.garfield,
            R.drawable.ben10,
            R.drawable.kungfupanda,
            R.drawable.snowwhite,
            R.drawable.mrgringe,
            R.drawable.scooby,
            R.drawable.shaggy,
            R.drawable.shrek,
            R.drawable.superman,
            R.drawable.lionking

    };
    private String imageNames[]={
            "Puss in Boots",
            "Mickey Mouse",
            "Garfield",
            "Ben 10",
            "Kungfu Panda",
            "Snow White",
            "Mr Grinch",
            "Scooby",
            "Shaggy",
            "Shrek",
            "Super Man",
            "Lion King"
    };
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private void mediaplayersong(String index)
    {

        switch(index)
        {
            case "Puss in Boots" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pussinboots);
                break;
            case "Mickey Mouse" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mickeymouse);
                break;
            case "Garfield" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.garfield);
                break;
            case "Ben 10" :mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ben10);
                break;
            case "Kungfu Panda" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kungfupanda);
                break;
            case "Snow White" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snowwhite);
                break;
            case "Mr Grinch" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mrgrinch);
                break;
            case "Scooby" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scooby);
                break;
            case "Shaggy" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scooby);
                break;
            case "Shrek" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shrek);
                break;
            case "Super Man" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.superman);
                break;
            case "Lion King" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lionking);
                break;
        }
    }
    private void mediaplayervoice(String index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case "Puss in Boots" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pussinbootstalk);
                break;
            case "Mickey Mouse" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mickeymousetalk);
                break;
            case "Garfield" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.garfieldtalk);
                break;
            case "Ben 10" :mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ben10talk);
                break;
            case "Kungfu Panda" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kungfupandatalk);
                break;
            case "Snow White" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snowwhitetalk);
                break;
            case "Mr Grinch" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mrgrinchtalk);
                break;
            case "Scooby" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scoobytalk);
                break;
            case "Shaggy" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shaggytalk);
                break;
            case "Shrek" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shrektalk);
                break;
            case "Super Man" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.supermantalk);
                break;
            case "Lion King" : mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lionkingtalk);
                break;
        }
    }
    private int arraySize=images.length;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scannerView=new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if(checkPermission())
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }


    }

    private boolean checkPermission()
    {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
    private void requestPermission()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permission[], int grantResults[])
    {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if(grantResults.length>0)
                {
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if(cameraAccepted)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        {
                            if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
                            {
                                displayAlertMessage("Please allow access!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                    }
                                });
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if(checkPermission())
            {
                if(scannerView==null)
                {
                    scannerView=new ZXingScannerView(this);
                    setContentView(scannerView);
                }
                scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                scannerView.startCamera();
            }
            else
            {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    public void displayAlertMessage(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", listener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }


    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        final String scanResult = result.getText();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(scanResult) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(scanResult))
        {
            final int number = Integer.parseInt(scanResult);

            if(number<arraySize) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainImageView);
                TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_character_name);

                imageView.setImageResource(images[number]);
                textView.setText(imageNames[number]);

                mediaplayersong(imageNames[number]);
                mediaPlayer.start();





                final Button buttonTalk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTalk);
                buttonTalk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaplayervoice(imageNames[number]);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

                final Button buttonSong=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSong);
                buttonSong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaplayersong(imageNames[number]);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

                final Button buttonGoBack=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGoBack);
                buttonGoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        setContentView(scannerView);
                        scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
                    }
                });


            }
            else
            {
                feedback("Invalid QR Code "+number);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            feedback("Invalid QR code! "+scanResult);
        }


    }


private void feedback(String status)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan result");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);

        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(status);
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
}











}
```

When I scan a bunch of QR codes while pressing the Song and Talk buttons as well to see how it works, after a certain attempts, the songs stop playing. It doesn't matter whether I click Song button or Talk button, no audio is played. Go Back button takes me perfectly to the scanner but I cannot get the audio to be played until I restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem exists due to the fact that you are trying to do relatively heavy tasks on the Main UI thread. So it may be giving you the non-functioning grayed out button. This can be solved by using AsyncTask, Handler, Thread, etc. in your program to scan QR Code, play music.

Check this link for using AsyncTask. [AsyncTask + WeakReference - Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKx0FuVriqA)

**Tip** While doing any job that requires extra memory space (RAM) or those that are computationally intensive, it is always better to put them in another thread so that the main UI thread is not disturbed. Otherwise the user will be forced to quit the unresponsive app.